# silverlight string format to limit the character count

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, string.format

I am using the `SubString` method to limit the character count.  Is this possible to do in XAML?  If so, how do you set the format string to limit the character count in XAML as in `String.Format`

For example:

> My Big text Message -> My Big text....

Answer (score 0):

Using the [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of `TextBlock` in Silverlight 4 should work:

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```

What's nice about this is that it will use actual text measurements instead of arbitrary character counts, since obviously not all characters are the same width.

Comment: but my textlock doesnt have fixed width.